# be_true rspec not found nameerror

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a problem with rspec and page object.  I have

```
 cell(:balance_type_tab_element, :id => 'a')
```

and then later down the line I have

```
def check_all
  check_navigation_to_and_from_balance_page
  check_printer_friendly_link
end
```

and then i also have

```
def check_allocation_by_balance_type
  balance_type_tab?
  puts "found tab"
  puts balance_type_tab_element.visible?
  balance_type_tab_element.visible?.should be_true
end
```

and

```
def check_navigation_to_and_from_balance_page
  //some other checks
  check_allocation_by_balance_type
end
```

then in a steps file

```
on_page(ParticipantBalanceDetailsPage).check_all
```

but i keep getting the error NameError: undefined local variable or method `be_true'

I tried googling but no luck so far, can someone help me out please?

Comment: Do other matchers work? `be_nil`, `be_an Array`, etc?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev NameError: undefined local variable or method `be_nil'

Comment: FYI i put a puts balance_type_tab_element.visible? and it returned true to the console.

Comment: where is this line of code - show some context.

Comment: Did you `require 'spec_helper'` at the top of spec file?

Comment: @FrederickCheung see revised question

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that is an rspec2 feature, i'm using regular rspec

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The various matcher methods are not automatically available in every context.  Consider that when you call `be_true`, you are sending the `be_true` message to `self`.  To make all matchers available in every context, RSpec would have to add ALL of the matcher objects to EVERY object in the system, which would be a terrible idea.

To make the matchers available in this context, you simply need to mix `RSpec::Matchers` in to your class:

```
class MyPageObject
  include RSpec::Matchers

  def check_allocation_by_balance_type
    balance_type_tab?
    puts "found tab"
    puts balance_type_tab_element.visible?
    balance_type_tab_element.visible?.should be_true
  end
end
```